# Good linear programming library for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linear-programming

I'm looking for a linear programming solver for C#. In the other words I'm looking for a library for C# that solves linear programming problems.

I need an easy to use library (so I can learn how to use it quickly), but it would be nice if it supported some features as automatic absolute values conversion (so I don't have to program the conversion myself). It is important that the library should be for free (not necessarily open source).

Good documentation is huge advantage for me. 10%-20% worse performance is not critical for my project.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969072/recommended-library-for-linear-programming-in-net

Answer (score 7):

[Math.NET](http://mathnet.opensourcedotnet.info/)

Read [C# linear algebra library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392857/c-linear-algebra-library)

**EDIT:** Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Solvers_and_scripting_.28programming.29_languages

This one might be what your looking for though. Says it works with .Net
http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/

Comment: That is question about Linear algebra. I'm looking for library specialized for Linear programming.

Comment: If some of those have specialized featured for LP please by more specific - provide information about how easy is to use the interface, what would you recommend to use...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WNLIB](http://www.willnaylor.com/wnlib.html), but it's plain C so you have to wrap it in a DLL library and then use it with C#.