# Open Source .Net Linear Programming Library

Tags: c#, .net, linear-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good linear programming library for C# ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363143/good-linear-programming-library-for-c)

Is there any free open source .Net linear programming library available?

Comment: Not sure whether the answer there is good enough because the answer suggested is geared towards linear algebra.